# Is Matlab an IDE?

Tags: matlab, ide

I'm a little confused as to what classifies as an IDE. According to Wikipedia:

> An integrated development environment (IDE) is a software application that provides comprehensive facilities to computer programmers for software development.

So is MatLab considered an IDE?

Comment: Yes, it is an 'IDE'; as already justified.

Comment: Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB): "MATLAB (matrix laboratory) is a multi-paradigm numerical computing environment and fourth-generation programming language." Part of the Matlab consists of an IDE (editor, file manager, debugging tools, profiling, etc.).

Comment: I'd say Matlab *has* an (optional) IDE.

Answer (score 2):

As with many things in software, there are no hard rules. But, if anything fits the description of IDE, matlab does.

The basic engine can be run purely from the command line, but when you marry that with the graphical environment, it has all the hallmarks of an IDE - richly featured text editor, debugging support, memory/workspace introspection, etc etc.

In some ways, the IDE is what you pay for. Minus that, there's little advantage over open source numerical languages like Python or Julia.

Answer (score 1):

MatLab workbooks could be considered and IDE. Depending how you define "comprehensive facilities" Vim is an IDE.